# Unable to inspect PICKER/DROPDOWN on Appium Inspector(Android)

Tags: android, react-native, selenium-webdriver, picker, appium-android

**Device**: Android

**App**: react native hybrid app

**Appium/Appium Inspector version**: Version 1.15.1 (1.15.1.20191013.2)

**Issue**:
I am unable to inspect a picker/dropdown. It doesn't appear in the app source at all.  Hence unable to find any locators to do further automation.

**Description**:

1. I open the android app on the mobile and navigate to a form where
   certain details need to be filled.One of the things to be filled is
   a dropdown.
2. I click on the arrow on the dropdown field
3. A NEW window/popup appears on top of the ORIGINAL form for the
   picker values to be displayed, which can be scrolled to see various
   values.
4. This new picker value window/pop up doesnt not come in the app
   source in the appium inspector at all

Can you please tell me a workaround to automate this scenario to select values in the dropdown.I am using Java + Selenium + Appium for the automation framework .

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have used uiautomatorviewer to inspect the element on Android App. Can you please check on uiautomatorviewer if not done already.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes already done that. Same issue. Cant inspect.